# What is a TextTracks tab in Network Chrome Inspector?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I recently have noticed `TextTracks` tab in a `Network` tab in chrome's web inspector. [image]

After some investigation I have never been able to see any resources appearing there, nor I was able to read/guess what can appear there and how can it be useful.

So what is this TextTracks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's for [TextTracks](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webvtt/):

> The WebVTT (Web Video Text Tracks) format is intended for marking up external text track resources.
>
> The main use for WebVTT files is captioning video content.

It's used to transfer text and subtitles for videos, for example:

> 00:11.000 --> 00:13.000
>
> We are in New York City
>
> 00:13.000 --> 00:16.000
>
> We're actually at the Lucern Hotel, just down the street
>
> 00:16.000 --> 00:18.000
>
> from the American Museum of Natural History

Here is a [tutorial about it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/) in which you can see it appearing in the chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

For filtering [time based text information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track) for HTML5 media elements. E.g. chapter info, subtitles, etc.

```
<video src="foobar.ogv">
  <track kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="subtitles_en.srt" srclang="en" default></track>
</video>
```